# Difference between moment() and moment(new Date())

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

```
$> moment.version
'2.18.1'
$> moment('Mon, 02 Jan 2017 06:00:00 -0800').format()
'2017-01-02T01:00:00-05:00'
$> moment(new Date('Mon, 02 Jan 2017 06:00:00 -0800')).format()
'2017-01-02T09:00:00-05:00'
```

It was my impression that the `moment` constructor could simply replace the `new Date()` constructor when parsing strings, for all formats that JS native `Date`s accept.

Is this me not understanding something or is this a bug?  It feels like a bug but I'd rather not submit an issue if I'm being an idiot.

It appears that this an acceptable format in their documentation also: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/

Comment: the latest method is used to convert js native Date instance into moment.js's instance, which is a wrapper of Date and owns more functions.

Comment: The first maybe uses the moment.js parser which must guess the format or the built-in parser. The second always uses the built-in parser.

Answer (score 2):

1. seems like they are the format is not recognized, see it yourself
2. also: `-08 00`,`-08`, `-8` also works but not recommended. Please follow this iso time format here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601.

```js
$(function(){
 var d = new Date('Mon, 02 Jan 2017 06:00:00 -0800');
 $('#test1').text(d);
 $('#test2').text(moment('Mon, 02 Jan 2017 06:00:00 -0800').format());
 $('#test3').text(moment('Mon, 02 Jan 2017 06:00:00 -08:00').format());
  $('#test4').text(moment('Mon, 02 Jan 2017 06:00:00 -800').format());
 $('#test5').text(moment(new Date('Mon, 02 Jan 2017 06:00:00 -0800')).format());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1"></div><br>
<div id="test2"></div><br>
<div id="test3"></div><br>
<div id="test4"></div><br>
<div id="test5"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's weird because the momentjs docs actually say that format *should* be recognized, which is the issue.  I submitted a bug, we'll see what they say.

(Also unfortunately I don't have control over the format, it's coming from an external service.  For now I'm just wrapping it in `new Date()`)